# Alternatives to shell_exec for clearing varnish in PHP

Tags: php, varnish

I have a script that I have inherited and it clears varnish cache on the server using shell_exec.

I have not ever been a big fan of using shell_exec but I do not know another way of clearing the cache directly from a PHP web page.

Are there other ways for this to do?

Comment: Why aren't you a fan of using `shell_exec()`?  What other way would you expect to exist?  Why specifically do you need to clear your cache from the script?

Comment: I agree with @Brad . As long as you're not passing input from the client to shell_exec, there really is no issue with using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have an REST [API](https://www.varnish-software.com/products/admin-console/cache-invalidation-api) for that purpose. You should give that a try

Answer (score 0):

Besides Varnish' admin console (paid software), Varnish has vcl methods to purge or ban objets from cache, but you'll need to add some logic to your current VCL config [1] [2]

The best method depends on what do you want to a achieve, purging a single object, perform a complete clean of a site...

**Logic to support complete host clean:**

```
acl purgers {
    "127.0.0.1";
    "192.168.0.0"/24;
}

sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.request == "BAN") {
        if (!client.ip ~ purgers) {
           error 405 "Method not allowed";
        }
        else {
           ban("obj.http.x-url ~ "/" && obj.http.x-host ~ " + req.http.host);
           error 200 "Banned";
        }
    }
}
```

**Logic to support single object purging (from Varnish Book):**

```
acl purgers {
    "127.0.0.1";
    "192.168.0.0"/24;
}

sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.request == "PURGE") {
            if (!client.ip ~ purgers) {
                    error 405 "Method not allowed";
            }
            return (lookup);
    }
}

sub vcl_hit {
    if (req.request == "PURGE") {
            purge;
            error 200 "Purged";
    }
}
sub vcl_miss {
    if (req.request == "PURGE") {
            purge;
            error 404 "Not in cache";
    }
}
sub vcl_pass {
    if (req.request == "PURGE") {
            error 502 "PURGE on a passed object";
    }
}
```

[1] https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/tutorial/purging.html

[2] https://www.varnish-software.com/static/book/Cache_invalidation.html